# Select all checkboxes depending on parent checkbox in SharePoint server 2016 on premise

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, 2016, custom-form

I have a document library in SharePoint 2016 on-prem.

The document library has a content type with columns that the user needs to complete when the user uploads a document. Since you cannot edit the document library form in InfoPath, I created a custom form based on the "editform.aspx" using SharePoint designer.

I opened my new custom form in advanced mode and inserted the JavaScript. The form needs to have cascading dropdowns (which work perfectly) and auto check/uncheck multiple checkboxes based on the parent checkbox (select all functionality).

I am using jQuery 3.4.1.min.js. Please see code below. I tried so many different ways, I could not get the checkboxes to check/uncheck automatically when the parent is checked. Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
relationshipList: "disciplinessub",
relationshipListParentColumn: "discipline",
relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
parentColumn: "Discipline",
childColumn: "Sub discipline",
debug: true
}); 
}); 

$(document).ready(function () {
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl00').on('change', function () {
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl01').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl02').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl03').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl04').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl05').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
});
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's a old problem in SharePoint OnPremises: a web page lifecycle delay. But, you can work around encapsulate your routine into setTimeout; this will be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   setTimeout(function(){
     $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "disciplinessub",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "discipline",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Discipline",
        childColumn: "Sub discipline",
        debug: true
     });
     $('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl00').on('change', 
         function () {
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl01').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl02').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl03').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl04').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl05').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
   }); 
   }, 1000);
});
```

Or you can try another SharePoint JS native approach, this is more assertive because the developer encapsulate the custom function into ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded tha contains the real time delay interval:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", sharePointReady);
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
     $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "disciplinessub",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "discipline",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "Discipline",
        childColumn: "Sub discipline",
        debug: true
     });
     $('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl00').on('change', 
         function () {
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl01').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl02').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl03').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl04').prop('checked', this.checked);
$('ctl00_ctl40_g_7a0cef3a_e14b_4ebe_80e8_b0c0c7b05b47_ff11_ctl00_ctl05').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
   }); 
   }, "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did more research, got a sample code and made a few changes to suit my requirements. Everything is working as expected now. Here is the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
var chkMychekbox = $(this).is(":checked");
if($(this).next('label').text()=="Group")
{
if (chkMychekbox == true)
 {
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function (i, item) {
$(this).prop("checked", true);
if($(this).next('label').text()!="Group")
{
$(this).prop("disabled", true);
}
});
 }
else
{
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function (i, item) {
$(this).prop("checked", false);
$(this).prop("disabled", false);
});
}
}
});
});
```